# Green properties keep reverting to a specific value

Tags: keyframes

So I'm doing this famous donut tutorial. Well, when I add a solidify modifier for the icing, I can't change its thickness to be less than 0.1 m. When I try, it lets me input any value like 0.0015 m, but when I hit enter, it goes back to that 0.1 m. I have the latest version of Blender. Also, the field for thickness is in **green** color if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You've keyframed the *Thickness* value, it will always come back to this value, put your mouse over the value and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to unkeyframe.